# SQLite3 - create table with column names from a text file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-wifi

I am trying to log WiFi access point strengths to possibly triangulate a person's position where GPS is not available (e.g. in a house). I want the column names to be BSSIDs or SSIDs, but I can only know the column names once a WiFi scan has been completed. I am thinking of making the user do a scan during the installation, output the BSSID or SSID to a text file, read the text file in the class that handles the database, and make my "create table" statement from what is in the text file. For example:

If the scan returns AP1, AP2, AP3, then the statement would be = create table accesspoints (AP1 INT, API2 INT, API3 INT)

But if the scan returns API1, API3, API4, then the statement would be = create table accesspoints (API1 INT, API3 INT, API4 INT)

I have been searching for hours and haven't found anything answers... is this even possible? I don't have much knowledge of databases in general, so can someone please help me? If anybody can think of another way to do it, please do not hesitate to share as well :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Custom naming the columns based on BSSID name sounds like a bad idea. Is the idea here to put the measured signal strength as a row under each BSSID?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but yes, that's what I want. Do you have suggestions on how I can organize the data better? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound very scalable. What happens if the access points in the house change? Why not just have a row corresponding to each access point?

Comment: Yeah, that's the other thing I am worried about... the app crashing when the access points change. However, if I have a row for each access point, how can I monitor changes in the signal levels? Thank you for answering!

Comment: Let's call your table with each access point as a row in it ACCESS_POINTS. What you could do, is each time you add a new access point to ACCESS_POINTS, you could create a new table called NAME_OF_ACCESS_POINT. Each record in that table would be a snap shot of the signal strength and any other data you wanted. Also, in the ACCESS_POINTS table, you'd have a column called TABLE_NAME that would be the name of the table that particular record corresponds to.

Comment: Store the access point measurements with access point name, signal strength, and a timestamp for when the measurement was taken.

Comment: @Kurtis Nusbaum Two questions off the top of my head:
1. Wouldn't I end up with a lot of tables then? A quick scan of where I am sitting gives me 12 access points already... so that's 13 tables?
2. How do I create tables from the ACCESS_POINTS table? Since ACCESS_POINTS would only have data after a WiFi scan... When I write codes I still wouldn't know what would be the data on that table? Thanks again.

Comment: @Michael - How would I be able to monitor the signal strength of a particular access point? Wouldn't a string form make calculation difficult in the future?

Comment: @Lily - You store all three pieces as separate fields of one record. So a record (row) in the sqlite table would have the three fields (not counting the primary key for the row). For example, you might store it as [1,"AP1",75,"2011-10-05 10:21:34"] where 1 is the primary key, "AP1" is the access point name, 75 is a FLOAT type number, and "2011-10-05 10:21:34" is a string representing the time and date of the measurement..

Comment: @Michael's solution is better actually. It sounds like you should read up on some basic database theory and database best practices. You seem a little shaky on some fundamentals. Here's some good thoughts: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DatabaseBestPractices

Comment: @Michael: For some reason I thought you meant to put it into one gigantic string (e.g. API1/75/time) yesterday, so that's why I thought it would be hard to parse the strength level. Guess I should sleep more... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum: To me it seems like your method of using a master list would look more organized, but I'll have to think about this more. Thanks!

Comment: @Lily: I thought as much. Also, you might want to check out some articles on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It will help you understand why it is more extensible (easy to add to) to setup a table in this manner.

Comment: @Michael Yes, normalizing. That's the word I was looking for.